# For Apache Camel, is it possible to have half of a route synchronous and the second half async?

Tags: apache-camel

I currently have a camel route that exposes a cxf endpoint. When a messages comes through the endpoint I would first enrich that message with some information from another webservice and then do more processing afterwards. However, I want make the first half of this route synchronous so I can send back a response to whomever called my exposed cxf endpoint.

The route looks something like this:

```
from(cxf:CxfEndpoint)
    .process(someProcessing)
    .to(cxf:ExternalCxfEndpoint)
    .to(activemq:queue:somequeue)

//return a response back to caller here

from(activemq:queue:somequeue)
    ... //additional processing here
    ...
```

The reason for this is because when a message comes via my exposed cxf endpoint I don't know if it's a valid message. I need to first validate it with the message enrichment. Once the message is enriched, I want let whomever sent the message know that their message is accepted but don't want them to wait for the message to make it through the whole route as that could take hours.

Does anyone know how this would work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is set [exchangePattern](http://camel.apache.org/exchange-pattern.html) to **InOnly** a.k.a. make it an [Event Message](http://camel.apache.org/event-message.html). This should have your route not wait for a reply from ActiveMQ. Camel exchange will default to **InOut** when it's originating from a web service, as in your case.

A related question with an answer from a Camel dev [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104260/effect-of-exchangepattern-inonly-on-mq-endpoint).

Also see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273094/apache-camel-jms-inonly-behaviour-when-broker-down) for some details on the behavior when your broker is down.

Comment: So why would happen if I changed a route from InOut() to InOnly() halfway through? Would a copy whatever was in the message immediately get returned to the callback location and the message proceed as normal?

Comment: Just setting the exchange pattern doesn't do anything by itself, but it influences the behaviors of endpoints that are called afterwards. You can and, in your case, should call only the activeMQ endpoint with InOnly pattern, so the response from the broker isn't waited for. But, you should really try it, because I haven't done it myself, so it's just a theory.

Comment: I will definitely try this out with a rudimentary route. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely , 100% possible. A simple example would be this :

1. From cxf endpoint
2. Store your request in a camel property or header
3. To xslt - generate xslt for cxf endpoint - Synchronous flow
4. Reset your original payload using set body.
5. Wiretap Endpoint - to any endpoint downstream or even a route , this becomes asynchronous . This won't take part in the above sync response .

Note- step 2 & 4 may not be required, it depends on your use case .

There are whole lots of things you can do, I just gave a very simple example . It doesn't need to be wiretap as well, but wiretap helps us not to write any additional custom exceptional handling.